# Get Delegation Amount from tezos api

Tags: delegating, api, rewards, delegation, indexer

I have list of delegator addresses for one baker.
I want to get how many tokens they delegated using tezos api.
Could anyone help me to get delegation amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a previous question you were given a link to TzKT indexer API. This API will likely offer the vast majority of things you need. Please make sure you read/research their documentation, as it is very detailed.

The question you've asked is not as simple as you think. Because delegating on Tezos follows liquid-POS, it means users can have a different amount delegated every cycle (~3 days). This API returns an array of cycle reward details for a given address. The `stakingBalance` in each object is what the user delegated: https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Rewards_GetDelegatorRewards

Also note that the first 5 cycles are future cycles, with the 6th being the current in-progress cycle. There are other API's available for cycle info

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please confirm if ```balance``` is delegated amount? I think it is account balance.

Comment: @Heindrick sorry its "stakingBalance". A user only ever delegates their entire balance, staking balance is a record of what the users balance was at the time the rewards were calculated (6 cycles ahead)

Comment: Ah, it means, user must delegate entire balance in tezos? Is it impossible to delegate partial?

Comment: @Heindrick not possible to delegate partial. There is no lock up time, there is no need to partially delegate

Comment: Got it, thank you for your answer. I will accept.

Comment: Hi @Simon McLoughlin, Just confirming. I want to delegate my balance to two bakers separately. So half delegate to one baker, the other half delegate to other baker. It is impossible in Tezos. Correct?

Comment: @Heindrick yes, you would need to create two wallets and split your funds. Delegating each wallet to a different baker